# Proof verification: Show $X$ $\times$ $Y$ is compact if $X$ and $Y$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Proof: Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact 
Let $(x_n,y_n)_i^\infty$ be a bounded sequence in $X \times Y$ 
Then $(x_n)_i^\infty$ and $(y_n)_1^\infty$ 
Since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, there exist convergent subsequences  $((x_n)_k)_1^\infty$
and $((y_n)_k)_1^\infty$   
Then $((y_n)_k, (x_n)_k)_1^\infty$ is a convergent subsequences of $(x_n,y_n)_i^\infty$
Since this shows $X \times Y$ is sequentially compact, $X \times Y$ is compact

Is this right? I tried to parallel the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem What could be improved? Thank you

Comment: You need to do more work to go from two individual sequences having convergent subsequences to the sequence of pairs having a convergent subsequence because the indices of the two individual subsequences may not match the indices in the sequence of pairs.

Comment: First state that there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}$ that converges and then $\{y_{n_j}\}$ is a sequence in $Y$ and it has a convergent subsequence $\{y_{n_{j_k}}\}$. Then use the fact that subsequences of convergent sequences converge to the same limit to point out that $x_{n_{j_k}}$ converges. Then show that the subsequence of pairs indexed by $n_{j_k}$ converges using the definition of convergence and the limits of the two individual sequences.

Comment: In a metric space, your approach can work. But $X\times Y$ is still compact for general topological spaces, however there, sequential compactness (every sequence has a convergent subsequence) and compactness (every open cover has a finite subcover) are not necessarily equivalent. It would be better to look for the more general topological proof instead of one by sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$, $Y$ are metric spaces, then you have the implication compact => sequentially compact (every sequence admits a convergent subsequence), as you have assumed. But as @Paul Sinclair mentioned in the comments, you need to explicitly show a convergent subsequence of $(x_j \times y_j)$ in $X \times Y$. This is not difficult: since $(x_m)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{m_n}) \to x_0$, consider $(y_{m_n})$, which has a convergent subsequence $(y_{m_{n_k}}) \to y_0$. We claim that the subsequence $(x_{m_{n_k}} \times y_{m_{n_k}})$ of $(x_j \times y_j)$ converges to $x_0 \times y_0$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x_0 \times y_0$ in $X \times Y$; we know that $U$ must contain a basis element of the form $B_X (x_0, \delta) \times B_Y (y_0, \varepsilon)$. There must exist a positive integer $N$ such that $x_{m_n} \in B_X (x_0, \delta)$ for each $n > N$ (obviously, this implies that there exists a positive integer $K_X$ such that $x_{m_{n_k}} \in B_X (x_0, \delta)$ for each $k > K_X$); and likewise there must exist a positive integer $K_Y$ such that $y_{m_{n_k}} \in B_Y (y_0, \varepsilon)$ for each $k > K_Y$. Now, for each $k > \max \{K_X, K_Y \}$, we have that $x_{m_{n_k}} \times y_{m_{n_k}} \in B_X (x_0, \delta) \times B_Y (y_0, \varepsilon) \subseteq U$, as desired. This shows $X \times Y$ is sequentially compact.

For metric spaces, the implication sequentially compact => compact holds, so it follows that $X \times Y$ is compact.

However, this approach breaks down if $X$ or $Y$ is not a metric space, because then we can't use the fact that they are sequentially compact. However, the claim is still true; it follows from the Tube Lemma, which states that if $Y$ is compact, then every open set $U \subseteq X \times Y$ containing $\{ x \} \times Y$ (where $x \in X$) admits a neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $\{ x \} \times Y \subseteq W_x \times Y \subseteq U$. If we let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover of $X \times Y$, then for each $x \in X$, consider the collection $\mathcal{A}_x$ of consisting of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ intersecting $\{ x \} \times Y$. Since $\{ x \} \times Y \simeq Y$, then $\{ x \} \times Y$ is compact, so that there exists some finite set $\{ {A_x}_{i_x} \} \subseteq \mathcal{A}_x$ covering it. The union of these ${A_x}_{i_x}$ is open; therefore, by the Tube Lemma, there exists some neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $\{ x \} \times Y \subseteq W_x \times Y \subseteq \bigcup_{i_x} {A_x}_{i_x}$. Since $X$ is compact, and $\mathcal{W} = \{ W_x | x \in X \}$ is a cover of $X$, then there exists some finite subcover $\{ W_{x_j} \} \subseteq \mathcal{W}$ of $X$. Obviously, $\{ W_{x_j} \times Y \}$ covers $X \times Y$. Therefore, the collection $\left\{ {A_{x_j}}_{i_{x_j}} \right\} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ is a finite subcover of $X \times Y$.